# Фиксация первой строки если ширина не известна

Tags: html, css

Добрый день!

У меня есть таблица из блоков `div`. 
Первая строка - заголовок. При попытке зафиксировать её с помощью `position:fixed` ширина всего заголовка и столбцов соответственно не совпадает с дальнейшим содержимым таблицы.

Никак не соображу как же её зафиксировать, наверняка кто-то уже сталкивался со схожей проблемой, очень прошу помочь!

```css
/* ОБЩИЕ СТИЛИ */
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#141615;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#0074af;
}
/* КОНЕЦ ОБЩИХ СТИЛЕЙ */

/* ФОРМЫ ДЛЯ ЗАГОЛОВКА */
.form {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.form .form-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.form .form-control {
  background: none;
  border:none;
/*  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;*/
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: white;
  width:110px;
  padding:0;
}
.caldate {
  max-width:80px;
}
.form .form-control:focus, .form .form-control:valid {
  outline: 0;
}
.form .form-control:focus + label, .form .form-control:valid + label {
  top: -15px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.form .form-control:focus + label .labelimg, .form .form-control:valid + label .labelimg {
  display: none;
}
.form label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: -2px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  word-break:break-all;
}

.form label span .labelimg {
  margin-top: -4px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-diapazon label span .labelimg {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.icosort {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#clear-filter {
  font-size:9px;
  font-weight:10;
  color:#6caed0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #6caed0;
}

#clear-filter:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
  color:#fff;
}
/* КОНЕЦ ФОРМ ДЛЯ ЗАГОЛОВКА */

/* ЧЕКБОКСЫ */
.checkbox, .radiobutton {
    display: none;
}
.checkbox-custom, .radiobutton-custom {
  position: relative;      /* Обязательно задаем, чтобы мы могли абсолютным образом позиционировать псевдоэлемент внютри нашего кастомного чекбокса */
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top:2px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
}
.checkbox-custom, .radiobutton-custom, .label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.checkbox:checked + .checkbox-custom::before {
    content: "";             /* Добавляем наш псевдоэлемент */
    display: block;          /* Делаем его блочным элементом */
    position: absolute;      /* Позиционируем его абсолютным образом */

     /* Задаем расстояние от верхней, правой, нижней и левой границы */
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 2px;
}
.white {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.red {
  border: 2px solid #dd2a1b;
}
.blue {
  border: 2px solid #0074af;
}
.small {
  width: 20px;             /* Обязательно задаем ширину */
  height: 20px;            /* Обязательно задаем высоту */
}
.big {
  width: 23px;             /* Обязательно задаем ширину */
  height: 23px;            /* Обязательно задаем высоту */
  margin-left:12px;   /* Делаем чекбокс по центру строки */
}
.fat-red {
  border: 3px solid #dd2a1b;
  width:21px;
  height:21px;
  margin-left:12px;   /* Делаем чекбокс по центру строки */
}
.checkbox:checked + .white::before {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.checkbox:checked + .red::before {
  background: #dd2a1b;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.checkbox:checked + .blue::before {
  background: #0074af;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
/* КОНЕЦ ЧЕКБОКСЫ */

/* ВСПЛЫВАЮЩАЯ ПОДСКАЗКА С КОНТАКТНОЙ ИНФОРМАЦИЕЙ */
.tooltip99 {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tooltip99 span {
  display:none;
}
.tooltip99:hover span {
  display:block;
  border-radius: 4px 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  top: 2em;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top:-10px;
  width: 280px;
  transition: all 1.2s ease;
}
.tooltipclassic {
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c6e2ff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.tooltiptable {
  width:255px;
  background: none;
}
.tooltiptable tr, .tooltiptable td {
  background: #fff;
}
.tooltiptable th {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-align:left;
}
.tooltiptable th:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
.tooltiptableico {
  width:30px;
}
.tooltip99 a {
  font-size:14px;
    }
/* КОНЕЦ ВСПЛЫВАЮЩЕЙ ПОДСКАЗКИ С КОНТАКТНОЙ ИНФОРМАЦИЕЙ */

/* ТАБЛИЦА */
.divTable{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
  margin-left:50px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  margin-top:-8px;
}
.otstup {
  padding-top:10px;
}
.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #0074af;
  display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
#zagolovok {
  background: #0074af;
  color:#fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#zagolovok div:first-child {
  border-radius:4px 0 0 0;
}

#zagolovok div:last-child {
    border-radius:0 4px 0 0;
}
.divblue {
  background-color:#ddedff;
}
.divwhite {
  background-color:#fff;
}
#prosrochka:hover {
  background-color:#fdcfcc;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
   -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
     -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
     -o-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
     -o-transition-delay: 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
     -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.divTableRow:hover {
  background-color:#b3daff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
   -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
     -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
     -o-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
     -o-transition-delay: 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
     -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.tableright {
  text-align:right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
/* КОНЕЦ таблицы */
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow" id="zagolovok">
<div class="divTableCell">
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" tabindex="1"><span class="checkbox-custom white small" title="Выбрать все"></span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" tabindex="2"><span class="checkbox-custom red small" title="Просроченные"></span></label>
</div>

<div class="divTableCell">
<div class="form">
  <a href="#" title="Сортировка" class="asrot"><img src="img/sort-white.png" class="icosort"></a>
  <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control caldate tcal" tabindex="3" required>
<label>Дата заказа <!--<span><img src="img/calendar-diapazon-white.png" class="labelimg"></span>--></label>
</div>
<br><a href title="Очистить фильтр" id="clear-filter">очистить фильтр</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="divTableCell">
<div class="form">
  <a href="#" title="Сортировка" class="asrot"><img src="img/sort-white.png" class="icosort"></a>
  <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control caldate tcal" tabindex="4" required>
<label>Дата поставки <!--<span><img src="img/calendar-diapazon-white.png" class="labelimg"></span>--></label>
</div>
<br><a href title="Очистить фильтр" id="clear-filter">очистить фильтр</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="divTableCell"><div class="form">
  <a href="#" title="Сортировка" class="asrot"><img src="img/sort-white.png" class="icosort"></a>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control caldate" type="text" tabindex="5" required>
    <label>Референс <span><img src="img/search-white.png" class="labelimg"></span></label>
</div>
<br><a href title="Очистить фильтр" id="clear-filter">очистить фильтр</a></div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="form">
  <a href="#" title="Сортировка" class="asrot"><img src="img/sort-white.png" class="icosort"></a>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" tabindex="6" required>
    <label>Поставщик <span><img src="img/search-white.png" class="labelimg"></span></label>
</div>
<br><a href title="Очистить фильтр" id="clear-filter">очистить фильтр</a></div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="form">
  <a href="#" title="Сортировка" class="asrot"><img src="img/sort-white.png" class="icosort"></a>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" tabindex="7" required>
    <label>Производитель <span><img src="img/search-white.png" class="labelimg"></span></label>
</div>
<br><a href title="Очистить фильтр" id="clear-filter">очистить фильтр</a></div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="form">
  <a href="#" title="Сортировка" class="asrot"><img src="img/sort-white.png" class="icosort"></a>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" tabindex="8" required>
    <label>Артикул <span><img src="img/search-white.png" class="labelimg"></span></label>
</div>
<br><a href title="Очистить фильтр" id="clear-filter">очистить фильтр</a></div></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="form">
  <a href="#" title="Сортировка" class="asrot"><img src="img/sort-white.png" class="icosort"></a>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" tabindex="9" required>
    <label>Наименование <span><img src="img/search-white.png" class="labelimg"></span></label>
</div>
<br><a href title="Очистить фильтр" id="clear-filter">очистить фильтр</a></div></div>
<div class="divTableCell">
  <a href="#" title="Сортировка" class="asrot"><img src="img/sort-white.png" class="icosort"></a>
  <label>Кол-во</label></div>
<div class="divTableCell tablerightt">
  <a href="#" title="Сортировка" class="asrot"><img src="img/sort-white.png" class="icosort"></a>
  <label>Цена</label></div>
</div>

<div class="otstup"></div>

<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"><span class="checkbox-custom blue big"></span></label></div>
<div class="divTableCell">27.04.2017</div>
<div class="divTableCell">28.04.2017</div>
<div class="divTableCell">118725-31521</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="tooltip99"><a href="#">ZSDV Рольф Полюстрово</a>
<span class="tooltipclassic">
<table class="tooltiptable">
<th colspan="2">ZSDV Рольф Полюстрово</th>
<tr><td class="tooltiptableico"><img src="img/man-mini-ico.png" width="15px" /></td><td>Бритченко Владимир </td></tr>
<tr><td class="tooltiptableico"><img src="img/phone-mini-ico.png" width="15px" /></td><td>8-916-128-12-35</td></tr>
<tr><td class="tooltiptableico"><img src="img/mail-mini-ico.png" width="15px" /></td><td><a href="mailto:Vladimir.Britchenko@abs-auto.ru" title="Написать письмо">Vladimir.Britchenko@abs-auto.ru</a></td></tr>
</table>
</span>
</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell">MOBIS/HYUNDAI/KIA</div>
<div class="divTableCell">ZA44BWD02ACA9601E</div>
<div class="divTableCell">ПЛЕНКА ЗАЩИТНАЯ БОКОВОЙ НАКЛАДНАЯ ПЛЕНКА ЗАЩИТНАЯ БОКОВОЙ БОКОВОЙ НАКЛАДНАЯ</div>
<div class="divTableCell tableright">9 999</div>
<div class="divTableCell tableright">1 256 878, 00</div>
</div>

<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"><span class="checkbox-custom blue big"></span></label></div>
<div class="divTableCell">27.04.2017</div>
<div class="divTableCell">28.04.2017</div>
<div class="divTableCell">118725-31521</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><div class="tooltip99"><a href="#">ZSDV Рольф Полюстрово</a>
<span class="tooltipclassic">
<table class="tooltiptable">
<th colspan="2">ZSDV Рольф Полюстрово</th>
<tr><td class="tooltiptableico"><img src="img/man-mini-ico.png" width="15px" /></td><td>Бритченко Владимир </td></tr>
<tr><td class="tooltiptableico"><img src="img/phone-mini-ico.png" width="15px" /></td><td>8-916-128-12-35</td></tr>
<tr><td class="tooltiptableico"><img src="img/mail-mini-ico.png" width="15px" /></td><td><a href="mailto:Vladimir.Britchenko@abs-auto.ru" title="Написать письмо">Vladimir.Britchenko@abs-auto.ru</a></td></tr>
</table>
</span>
</div></div>
<div class="divTableCell">MOBIS/HYUNDAI/KIA</div>
<div class="divTableCell">ZA44BWD02ACA9601E</div>
<div class="divTableCell">ПЛЕНКА ЗАЩИТНАЯ БОКОВОЙ НАКЛАДНАЯ</div>
<div class="divTableCell tableright">9 999</div>
<div class="divTableCell tableright">1 256 878, 00</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: css бы тоже изрядно помог

Comment: NeedHate, я добавил стили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сети нашел такое довольно изящное [решение](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/).

Смысл такой: мы дублируем заголовок таблицы в `<div>` и его фиксируем `position: absolute;` и фиксируем по верху (`top:0`). Поскольку у заголовка таблицы и у самой таблицы `position: static;` то координаты рассчитываются относительно блока со скролом (в данном случае `section`, может быть и `body`).

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 180px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bgcolor</td>
          <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>border</td>
          <td>1,""</td>
          <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellpadding</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellspacing</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>frame</td>
          <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>rules</td>
          <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>summary</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>width</td>
          <td>pixels, %</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: но у меня же не таблица, а DIVы

Comment: Это не принципиально, они повторяют табличную верстку

Comment: Интересный пример, но у него есть 1 очень серьёзный изъян - в нём мы задаём высоту .container - это значение нельзя предугадать когда таблица генерится из базы данных.

Comment: Но логика примера вроде применима. Попробую, спасибо!